# Conditional insertions of column values to Pandas Dataframe from multiple external lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
    DATE         PARTICULARS                DR      CR  
0   04-03-2017   UPI PA                     10000   0.0 
1   04-03-2017   UPI PA                     10000   0.0 
2   04-03-2017   POS BPCL COCO PU           1000    0.0 
3   04-03-2017   BRN PYMT CARD              2536    0.0 
4   04-03-2017   UPI PA                     10050   0.0 
5   04-03-2017   POS BPCL COCO PU           1000    0.0 
6   04-04-2017   INB IFT PARTY TRANSFER     60000   0.0
```

I have a dataframe as above.

And I have three lists:

```
fuel = ['hpcl', 'bpcl']
cc = ['BRN', 'DEL', 'RQ']
ref = ['transfer', 'tx']
```

I want to create a 'Label' column df['Label'] which will append the `name of the list` to the column if any of the words in the `list` are found in the `PARTICULARS` column like shown below:

```
    DATE         PARTICULARS                   DR       CR      Label
0   04-03-2017   UPI PA                        10000    0.0     Nan
1   04-03-2017   UPI PA                        10000    0.0     Nan
2   04-03-2017   POS BPCL COCO PU              1000     0.0     fuel
3   04-03-2017   BRN PYMT CARD                 2536     0.0     cc
4   04-03-2017   UPI PA                        10050    0.0     Nan
5   04-03-2017   POS BPCL COCO PU              1000     0.0     fuel
6   04-04-2017   INB IFT PARTY TRANSFER        60000    0.0     ref
```

I tried the following but it only appended NaN's to my '`Label`' column.

```
def add_label(lst):
    for x in lst:
        if x in df.PARTICULARS.str.split():
            df.loc[x, 'Label'] == lst.__name__
    return df

df['Label'] = df.apply(lambda x: add_label(Fuel))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.select` with `pd.Series.str.contains`:

```
df["Label"] = np.select([df["PARTICULARS"].str.contains("|".join(i), case=False) for i in (fuel, cc, ref)],
                        ["fuel", "cc", "ref"], "Nan")
# or str.contains(r"\b"+"|".join(i)+r"\b",...) if you want to add a word boundary

print (df)

         DATE             PARTICULARS     DR   CR Label
0  04-03-2017                  UPI PA  10000  0.0   Nan
1  04-03-2017                  UPI PA  10000  0.0   Nan
2  04-03-2017        POS BPCL COCO PU   1000  0.0  fuel
3  04-03-2017           BRN PYMT CARD   2536  0.0    cc
4  04-03-2017                  UPI PA  10050  0.0   Nan
5  04-03-2017        POS BPCL COCO PU   1000  0.0  fuel
6  04-04-2017  INB IFT PARTY TRANSFER  60000  0.0   ref
```